# Microsoft Teams: Group Call with multiple external users

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to call two users from microsoft.com domain using my organization teams account(opened on the desktop app), but I'm not able to contact them on a group call. Can anyone please help me understand what can be the possible issue & how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To schedule meetings with your employees, clients, External users and other guests, use Microsoft Teams.

- In Microsoft Teams, in the left navigation, choose **Meetings**.
- Choose **Schedule a meeting**.
- In the **New meeting box**, enter a *Title* and *Location* for the meeting.
- Enter a **Start and End time and date**.
- In the **Details** box, enter a description of the meeting and any other details you
  want to add, such as a meeting agenda.
- Under *Invite people*, enter the names of employees or clients that you want to invite.
- If you see **Tentative or Busy** below any names, choose one of the Free times provided, or click *Scheduling assistant* for more options.
- Choose **Schedule a meeting**.